# Se puede agrupar un hash pero a la vez cambiar el key del mismo y te entregue un nuevo hash?

Tags: array, ruby, hash

```
ventas = {
    lexus: 15000,
    hyundai: 20000,
    fiat: 15000,
    audi: 15000,
    chevrolet: 60000,
    honda: 15000,
    }
    
a =  ventas.each_slice(3).map{ |trim| trim }
p a # => [[[:lexus, 15000], [:hyundai, 20000], [:fiat, 15000]], [[:audi, 15000], [:chevrolet, 60000], [:honda, 15000]]]`
```

se espera new_hash `{:lote1 => 60000, :lote2 => 90000}`

Answer (score 1):

Puedes realizar casi todo en el `map`, utilizando `with_index` y `sum` para sumar los lotes, y convertir todo a *hash* al final:

```
ventas.
  each_slice(3).
  map.with_index { |lote, i| ["lote#{i + 1}".to_sym, lote.sum { |_, monto| monto }] }.
  to_h
#=> {:lote1=>50000, :lote2=>90000}
```

El `_` en `lote.sum { |_, monto| monto }` representa una variable que no se utiliza, por lo que generalmente se opta por nombrarla así (`_`) y poder identificarla rápidamente. En este caso específico esa variable tiene el nombre de la marca, pero ese valor no requiere (solo utilizamos el `monto`).

Para mayor claridad en el código, podrías cambiar `|_, monto|` por `|_marca, monto|`, lo cual no afecta en la ejecución y deja claro el valor que tiene esa variable aunque no se utilice.

---

También podrías cambiar `lote.sum { |_, monto| monto }` por `lote.sum(&:last)` y obtendrías el mismo resultado:

```
ventas.
  each_slice(3).
  map.with_index { |lote, i| ["lote#{i + 1}".to_sym, lote.sum(&:last)] }.
  to_h
#=> {:lote1=>50000, :lote2=>90000}
```

Este último es más apegado al estilo *Ruby*, pero podría debatirse cuál de los dos expresa mejor el objetivo del código.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con:

```
ventas = {
    lexus: 15000,
    hyundai: 20000,
    fiat: 15000,
    audi: 15000,
    chevrolet: 60000,
    honda: 15000,
    }
    
a =  ventas.each_slice(3).map{ |trim| trim }
count = 0
new_hash = a.inject({}) do |hash, array| 
  numeros = array.flatten.select { |v| v.is_a? Integer }
  suma = numeros.inject(:+)
  key = "lote#{count += 1}".to_sym
  hash.merge!({key => suma})
end
new_hash # => {:lote1=>50000, :lote2=>90000}
```